# Sharing a .emacs between computers. Emacs overwrites .emacs that is hard linked in my Dropbox

Tags: emacs, initialization, config

I want to keep my .emacs in my Dropbox folder, to sync it between work and home.

I moved my .emacs to my dropbox folder and then (hard) linked it like:
`ln ~/Dropbox/.emacs ~/.emacs`

Then if I open ~/.emacs in emacs, edit and save it, it deletes the .emacs hard link and overwrites it with a fresh .emacs so the linkage is gone. I have two seperate copies, a newer ~/.emacs and an out-of-date ~/Dropbox/.emacs.

I could edit the ~/Dropbox/.emacs file instead, but sometimes emacs write something into the .emacs by itself (say customizing variables) and the issue occurs again.

How can I get emacs to not overwrite that particular file? Or is there a way to launch emacs and tell it where to read the .emacs from?

**[edit SOLVED]**
Some guy posted a comment about using soft-symlinks instead of hard-links. This actually works for me and solved the issue. But then the guy who posted the comment deleted it again for some reason. ~thank you  who ever it was~

Comment: Your terminology is a bit confused. "Hard sym link" is a contradiction, and "soft sym-link" is a tautology. There are "hard links" and "sym[bolic] links", and the *latter* are also known as "soft links".

Comment: thank you for pointing this out. I corrected the above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would heartily recommend that you place your emacs configuration files into a GIT repository.

I have a github repository for all of my elisp file, which enables me to share the files with any computer and track changes.

Comment: Do you have the repo in your home folder? How do you make emacs read the .emacs file, via a symlink?

Comment: @LeoUfimtsev No, you keep .emacs.d under version control, and use the preferred config file of `~/.emacs.d/init.el`

Comment: Oh I see. (Le me just read this business: http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html) Thank you for comment.

Comment: I have a very rudimentary .emacs file, that loads my actual configuration files within a dedicated elisp directory. 


The elisp directory is under version control. You can see the config files at [Github](https://github.com/cmcmahan/elisp) 


My .emacs is copied to the repository (manually) as emacs-dotemacs.el 


@LeoUfimtsev, I prefer to keep my configurations outside of the .emacs.d directory. Using the .emacs with my elisp directory has worked well for me so far. –  Chris McMahan

Answer (score 1):

I used softlinks instead, which solved the issue.

Comment: I was that guy! I deleted my comment because, upon further research, it looked like this might break too. I was going to recommend moving `~/.emacs` to `~/.emacs.d/init.el` and linking the `~/.emacs.d/` *directory* to Dropbox instead. Apparently [Dropbox likes links to directories more than links to files](http://askubuntu.com/questions/237107/how-do-symbolic-links-work-in-dropbox).

Comment: But in the above, it says that dropbox breaks symlinks. But here I have a file in dropbox and I symlink to it?

Comment: Yes, I'm not sure what's going on. Could be different versions of Dropbox, or you may find that your symlink breaks after you access it from the other machine. But I'm fairly confident that the issue is a Dropbox one, not an Emacs one.

Comment: hmm, I see. I'll try to modify things from home and see if things break tomorrow. Will post update tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative suggestion (which I use): Let `~/.emacs` (or `~/.emacs.d/init.el`) be different for each computer you use. Use that file to set up system-dependent paths— the location of your Dropbox directory, the path to `diff`, the colors that work best on that monitor, whatever. Then load (`require`) a common file that contains all of your usual (system-independent) configuration. Call it "`leo-init`" or something.

And I heartily agree with the prior suggestion to put your emacs config into a git repository (or other vcs). It's fantastic peace of mind to know that if you screw something up, you can go back to the way it was— or examine in detail what exactly you changed and when.